# Saving PDF files to my iOS app

Tags: ios8

Is there any way to save the PDF files that come as attachment in Mail to my iOS app like copying  to the iBooks ?

Any tutorials would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can open that file in your app. Then you can save it where ever you want. check this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1